# How to locate the js statement that jumps to another web page?

Tags: javascript, firefox-developer-tools, javascript-debugger

When I open some web pages, they may jump to another web page automatically after a while. For example, if you open https://list.jd.com/list.html?cat=670,677,688 it will jump to cfe.m.jd.com/..., then further jump to passport.jd.com that asks you to login. I think on the page list.jd.com/..., there must be a statement like `window.location.href=...`that causes the jump. But where is the statement? How can I find the statement in a systematic way? I mean I can press F12 and set a breakpoint on that statement then refresh the page to stop at that statement.

Comment: That first "jump" doesn't even have anything to do with JavaScript - that's a HTTP redirect with status code 302.

Comment: @CBroe If you visit the first url from an ip in China, it will show for a while then jump to the second, then the third url. But that is not important. What I want to know is a systematic way to find the statement that causes the jump.

Comment: In your browser dev tools, network panel, you can look at the "initiator" column, that will tell you what caused the request. That might refer to a script file, or the document itself, but it is hard to find the actual lines responsible based on that. Maybe adding a _watchpoint_ for when the value of `location.href` changes, helps a bit more. (_If_ that actually is what is causing the redirect.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all redirects are done using JavaScript so that means there won't always be a `location.href` to look for in a script. In fact it's quite the opposite. Most redirects like the one you gave in your example are done on the server, load balancer or most likely by the DNS provider, more explanation [here](https://www.site24x7.com/learn/dns-redirects.html#:%7E:text=A%20DNS%20redirect%20is%20a,the%20one%20it%20initially%20requested.).

If you `curl` the url in your example you will see there is a `302`:

```bash
curl -s https://list.jd.com/list.html?cat=670,677,688
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

You can tell `curl` to follow this redirect with the `-L` option:

```bash
curl -sL https://list.jd.com/list.html?cat=670,677,688
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1.0,viewport-fit=cover" />
  <title>京东安全</title>
<link href="https://cfe.m.jd.com/privatedomain/risk_handler/03101900/css/app.34c74a0c.css" rel="preload" as="style"><link href="https://cfe.m.jd.com/privatedomain/risk_handler/03101900/js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="https://cfe.m.jd.com/privatedomain/risk_handler/03101900/js/chunk-vendors.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="https://cfe.m.jd.com/privatedomain/risk_handler/03101900/css/app.34c74a0c.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>

<body>
  <div class="ipaas-floor-app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cfe.m.jd.com/privatedomain/risk_handler/03101900/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cfe.m.jd.com/privatedomain/risk_handler/03101900/js/app.js"></script></body>
```

There a couple of scipts listed in that response so you could see what is happening in those scripts.

The best way would be to go into your dev tools (for illustration I'll use Chrome) and select:

- `Sources` tab.
- On the right-hand side select `Event Listener Breakpoints`
- `Load`
- Now check `Load` and `Unload`.

Paste `https://list.jd.com/list.html?cat=670,677,688` and see the various stages of the `Load` and `Unload`. The browser will pause at these breakpoints. Good luck with your exploration.

Answer (score 0):

there's a 302 response coming, meaning its a redirect configuration on the server not javascript.